# Mac preview space broken

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, finder

In Finder you can preview files just by hitting space.

This function is broken since some days. Where to look at to repair this? Is there a setting in library, preferences or elsewhere?

Using: Snow Leopard, latest updates installed.

Comment: Does `Command-Y` work as shortcut in Finder? Does `qlmanage -p path/to/file` work in Terminal?

Comment: Command-Y does not work, qlmanage works.

Comment: Is the menu item *File » Quick Look* activated or deactivated when a file is selected in Finder? Is its keyboard shortcut `Command-Y`? Does Quick Look work in other applications, such as Mail (click an attachment once, then press `Space`)?

Comment: Well, it is strange... Shortly after the problem occurred it worked again, then the problem occurred again. At the moment it works... Maybe some kind of background service could be inactive some times?

Comment: Does it work for other user accounts on the same machine?